# How to select weekdays only in a Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with two columns: column A has dates, column B has data. I want to compute the average of the data in B that corresponds to only week (work) days.

How can I write it as a formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WEEKDAY functionality to determine the day of the week, and then compute the Average of all days that are not Sunday (1) or Saturday (7).

```
WEEKDAY(number, type)
```

> Returns the day of the week for the given number (date value). The day is returned as an integer based on the type. Type determines the type of calculation: type = 1 (default), the weekdays are counted starting from Sunday (Monday = 2), type = 2, the weekdays are counted starting from Monday (Monday = 1), type = 3, the weekdays are counted starting from Monday (Monday = 0).

from: https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240285

The you would need a collection of SumIF statements for each week day 2-6, and a count of them to determine an average.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Is it sth like this: =SUMIF(B1:B10, WEEKDAY(A1:A10)>2 & WEEKDAY(A1:A10)<6, 1) ?

Comment: It would probably be easier to add another column with the Weekday parameter, and then us that in your sumif and countif.
I made a column C as =WEEKDAY(A1), Assuming the date is in Column A and the data in B:
Your query would look like this:
=(SUMIF(C1:C40,2,B1:B40)+SUMIF(C1:C40,3,B1:B40)+SUMIF(C1:C40,4,B1:B40)+SUMIF(C1:C40,5,B1:B40)+SUMIF(C1:C40,6,B1:B40))/(CountIF(C1:C40,2)+(CountIF(C1:C40,3)+(CountIF(C1:C40,4)+(CountIF(C1:C40,5)+(CountIF(C1:C40,6))))))

Comment: Sorry for how messy it is

Comment: bquaresma: How do I modify the query so that I only take the work days within the last 1 month?